# Consuming message in sequence from Jms in mule flow

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I have a tibco queue where we receive messages from producers and a mule flow is consuming these messages. I have numberOfConsumers set to 20 in jms:connector. some time when the load is high my messages are received out of sequence in the flow. 
I want my flow to receive messages in sequence without making it single threaded.

Below is the flow with logger in the beginning of the flow:

```
<flow name="some name" doc:name="ServiceId-8" initialState="started"> 
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${queue1}" connector-ref="jmsconnector" doc:name="JMS"> 
    <logger message="Receiving Message: #[message.payload]"  category="com.xyz" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>  
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>  
     <processor....
     <component....
     ........
     ........
</flow>
```

**Connector:**

```
<jms:connector name="jmsconnector" specification="1.1" username="${name}" password="${pass}" validateConnections="true" jndiInitialFactory="factoryClass" jndiProviderUrl="${url}" connectionFactoryJndiName="GenericConnectionFactory" cacheJmsSessions="true" eagerConsumer="true" forceJndiDestinations="true" numberOfConsumers="20" persistentDelivery="true" maxRedelivery="5" doc:name="JMS"> 
    <spring:property name="jndiProviderProperties"> 
        <spring:map> 
        <spring:entry key="java.naming.security.principal" value="${name}"/>  
        <spring:entry key="java.naming.security.credentials" value="${pass}"/>  
        </spring:map>  
    </spring:property>  
    <reconnect-forever/>  
</jms:connector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take any of the approach below.

1. Set the queue to be **exclusive**. This would enable server to send message to only one consumer.
2. using **JMSXGroupID** property of JMS. This would ensure that messages are processed in order for particular group coming in the header "JMSXGroupID". e.g. if there are 5 messages with JMSXGroupID set as "customer1" for 3 messages and "customer2" for 2 messages. Then the processing of 3 messages under "customer1" and processing of 2 messages under "customer2" will be sequential. However messages for both groups will be executed in parallel.